# Dynamically add blocks to GrapesJS

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I'm retrieving dynamic HTML, CSS and JS codes from the database. How can I create Blocks with this?
Currently, this is my code,

```
editor.BlockManager.add(aBlock['name'], {
    id: aBlock['name'],
    label: aBlock['name'],
    category: aBlock['category'],
    content: aBlock['html'],
    style: aBlock['css'],
    script: aBlock['css'],
  });
```

But its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try console.log() after adding block element.

```
console.log('All block element ', blockManager.getAll());
```

If your new block element is there is block array of objects then just render block element again.

```
editor.BlockManager.render()
or maybe like this
editor.BlockManager.render(blockManager.getAll())
```

https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/block_manager.html#render

Answer (score 1):

You can push components in array  named "components", in my example there are two components.

NOTE 1: I'm using angularjs for my example:

```
var components = [
      {
        'id' : '0001',
        'data' : {
             label: `<div>
              <div class="my-label-block">Párrafo</div>
            </div>`,              
            content: {
            type: "text",
            content: '<span style="margin:0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">Ejemplo.</span>'
          },
          attributes: {
          class: "fa 0001",
          id: '0001'
          },
          category: 'Basic element'
        }
      }
,
    {
      'id' : '0002',
      'data' : {
             label: `<div>
              <div class="my-label-block">Botón</div>
            </div>`,                  
            content:`
                    <a style="font-family: Arial;">Button </a>
            `,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true,
            stylable: true,
            category: 'Basic element',
            selectable: true,
            class : 'fa 0002',
            attributes: {
            class: "fa 0002",
            id: '0002'
            }

      }
    }
]
```

and then, dinamically insert in your grapesJS instance:

```
let bm = $scope.editor.BlockManager;
          for (i=0;i<components.length;i++){
            if(components[i].id && components[i].data){
              bm.add(components[i].id, components[i].data)
            }
          }
```